# Why does this oracle query return null? (avg on number field)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm pulling my hair out this morning, as I'm trying to select a simple average from a single field from a table in an Oracle database.   My table has 31 rows, the column in question is called AGE and I just want an average.   The column is of type "number" and there are no nulls in it.

```
SELECT AVG(AGE)
FROM COLLECTIONS.CUSTOMERS
```

This query always returns null.   I have also tried:

```
SELECT SUM(AGE)/COUNT(AGE)
FROM COLLECTIONS.CUSTOMERS
```

with the same result.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your transaction commited? What does a `SELECT COUNT(age), SUM(age) FROM collections.customers` return?

Comment: It returns the expected results:  31, 1106

Comment: can you setup the data in a fiddle? (sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Can you just try SELECT AVG(NVL(AGE,0)) FROM COLLECTIONS.CUSTOMERS and see the result.

Comment: @realspirituals I'm getting one error after another trying to import my schema on the fiddle.   My export function made insert statements with strings being inserted into dates, etc.   It'll take me a bit to get that cleaned up.

Comment: @TeeKea There are no null values in the column, but I tried that anyway.  Still null.

Comment: You can simply post the insert statements too

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "COLLECTIONS"."CUSTOMERS" 
   ( "CUSTNO" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "CNAME" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CADR1" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CADR2" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CCITY" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CSTATE" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CZIP" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "CPHONE" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
 "STATUS" NVARCHAR2(2000) DEFAULT 'NEW' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "NEXTACT" DATE DEFAULT trunc(sysdate) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "AGE" NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "BALANCE" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
  PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTNO") ENABLE
   )`

Comment: I can't get it into the fiddle, it keeps giving me server errors.   This works fine on the Oracle deployment here.   Here's an example record:

`INSERT INTO "CUSTOMERS" ("CUSTNO","CNAME","CADR1","CADR2","CCITY","CSTATE","CZIP","CPHONE","STATUS","AGE","BALANCE") VALUES (9163,'OLYNICK TRANSIT','13874 STATE HWY.27',NULL,'CADOTT','WI','54727-5017','715-289-4749','LETTER1',19,'444.1');`

Comment: if you're on windows, try rebooting

Comment: In the `INSERT` that you posted, there are two invisible characters after the column name `AGE` (14844044 and 14844043). Could this be related to your problem? Also, please edit them into your question and remove the comments, and make sure to try it exactly with the posted statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating a sample table with single column (age). I kept data type `int` and `number` both and getting expected result:

`INTEGER` : [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cee14/1/0)

`NUMBER` : [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8d1d/1)

`NUMBER` (with same datatype as OP): [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/209fe/1)

Comment: I've also tried with `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` and it still works.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you guys, but this doesn't answer the question of why it's not working for me.

Comment: @MichaelPodrybau, I am not sure what is going wrong with your setup. I have recreated the schema using the DDL & DML you have provided. It is working as expected. Check the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e628/1